# char[] to char* in struct

Tags: c++, struct, char

I am trying to get char[]to char* in struct,when I assign it `p->name2=name` it shows me the right word, but when I try to go through linked list with for loop, it only shows me last word so many times how much are words in file. why it happens? And I can't use string or libraries. Do I really need to get each word as char symbol (getchar())?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
struct elem{
    char* name2;
    elem* next;
};
int main(){
    elem *first = NULL, *last = NULL,*q=NULL, *p;
    fstream fin,fout;
    char name[255];
    fin.open("pasts.txt",ios::in);
    fin>>name;
    while (fin){
        p = new elem;
        p->next=NULL;
        p->name2=name;
        if(first==NULL){
            first=last=p;
        }
        else{
            p->next=last;
            last=p;
        }
        fin>>name;
    }
    fin.close();
    for(p=last;p!=NULL;p=p->next){
        cout<<p->name2<<" ";
    }
```

Comment: Problems like this is what `std::string` is designed to avoid.

Comment: Yes! You have to copy the *actual characters* or all your nodes will have a `name2` value that points to the *same* string. (There is almost certainly a duplicate that's very close to this, so I'm not posting an answer.)

Comment: `char name[255];` is one variable. `char* name2;` in all of your nodes point at this variable. If one node changes the variable, all nodes see the same thing because they ARE the same thing.

Comment: You're using C++, yet you're writing C (because you're using raw-pointers and character buffers). Use `std::string`!

Answer (score 0):

You declared local variable `name` having array type

```
char name[255];
```

In this statement

```
p->name2=name;
```

the data member `name2` of all allocated nodes points to the same first character of the character array `name`.

So what in this array is stored is what the data member `name2` of all nodes points to.

You have to make a copy of the stored string in the array `name` by allocating dynamically for it memory and its address assigning to the data member `name2`.

You could do it the following way

```
    p->name2 = new char[strlen( name ) + 1];
    strcpy( p->name2, name );
```

Answer (score 0):

> And I can't use string or libraries.

Typically this means: The instructor forbid the use of those. That's OK. But I just want to clarify that because of this, the answer will point to a sub-optimal solution.

So, you have multiple options:

Option 1: Use an array.

```
struct elem{
    char name2[256];
```

Then, you'll need to strcpy name into name2. And be careful about not overflowing.

Option 2: Use dynamic memory.

```
l = strlen(name);
name2 = new char[l + 1];
//strcpy
//and deal with delete[] later on.
```

Option 3: Use std::string anyway and try to educate the instructor. YMMV.

Comment: If you're going to use library functions like `strlen` (which OP is not allowed), then `strdup` would be the way to go, IMHO.